# Multiple Search Filters MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a database containing information about a person. Lets say I want to search people from a country. So I type in USA and got 10 data. After that, I would want to further narrow down to people who are male.

How do I do a SQL that can first search for country, then search for gender.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM people 
  WHERE country like $search1%
  ORDER BY ASC ";
```

And

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM people 
  WHERE country like $search1%
  AND Gender = $search2
  ORDER BY ASC ";
```

How do I combine them into one $sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try to combine all cases with this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE (country LIKE %$search1% AND $search2='')
OR ($search1='' AND gender=$search2)
OR (country LIKE %$search1% AND gender=$search2)";
```

Add your own `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
SELECT * 
FROM people 
WHERE 
((country = ('USA') AND gender = 'male') 
OR 
(country LIKE ('USA') OR gender LIKE 'male'))
ORDER BY ASC
```

First line `((country = ('USA') AND gender = 'male')`

For both
Second line `(country LIKE ('USA') OR gender LIKE 'male'))`

For either put `'%'` in the one you don't need.

For example `(country LIKE ('USA') OR gender LIKE '%'))`

Comment: I mean like i can filter my data either by just choosing a country or choosing a gender or choosing a country and gender. 3 ways.

Comment: his question is how to combine two sql query this is not proper.

Comment: @user3440156 first check, which filter has value to retrieve record.then combine query according to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sub query:

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM people    WHERE country like $search1% )
>   as people1   WHERE Gender = $search2   ORDER BY ASC

Answer (score -1):

you can combine this. first check the filter has a value or not.

to check using if condition and concate a string and then execute it, like a.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM people WHERE 1 ";
if($search1% != NULL){
   $sql.="AND country like $search1% ";
}
elseif($search2 != NULL){
   $sql.="AND Gender = $search2 ";
}
$sql.="ORDER BY ASC ";
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways

1. Create view in MySql For such complex query
2. write a function in php to build query for above

   ```
    <?php
      function searchQuery($key,$gender,$order){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE country like %$key% AND Gender = $gender ORDER BY $order"
       $query= mysql_query($sql);
       while($data= mysql_fetch_array($query))  {
          //Do your stuff here and collect in one variable say $searchData
       }
        return $searchData
      }
   ```

Hope this will help you